# Use the same RecyclerView adapter twice

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Is it possible to use the same RecyclerView adapter twice with other getItemCount? Once I need only 6 items, and in other activity I need all of them.

```
 @Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 6;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

You can pass a `boolean` flag in your adapter class

and based on that `boolean` variable you can returns item in your `getItemCount()` method

> SAMPLE CODE

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<String> arrayList;
    boolean flag;

    public MyAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<String> arrayList, boolean flag) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
        this.flag = flag;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return flag ? 6 : arrayList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While creating object of adapter class, you can define for which type you want to return value.

But you have to put condition when count is less than 6.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to use the same RecyclerView adapter twice with other getItemCount?

Suppose the adapter keeps its data in some List called *data*. Then you can achieve this by introducing a field `private int maxItems = -1;` as well as a method to set the maximum number of items to be displayed:

```
public void setMaxItems(int maxItems){
    this.maxItems = maxItems;
}
```

Now you can override `getItemCount()` as follows:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (data == null){
        return 0;
    }
    if (maxItems >= 0){
        return Math.min(maxItems, data.size());
    }
    return data.size();
}
```